# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't start, but produces a process

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 professional. Recently, something broke.
When try to run it, it launches only once in about four trials. However, even if it doesn't launch, it produces a `devenv.exe` process that can be seen in task manager.
Does dummy processes (each successful run of VS produces a few o them), are problematic to kill simultaneously, and cause problem while I try to install some extensions.

I've tried deleting `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5a56ecad\privateregistry.user.bin` (I found this solution somewhere, but I can't find it now). This seemed to help, but only temporarily (after some time, problem appeared again). And it also corrupts one of my extensions, which seems to depend on this file.

Using Windows 7.

Comment: You may get a clue by using Process Explorer to check a stack trace of threads in the hung devenv.exe.

Comment: I have the same problem and your question prompted me to do a little more research into the privateregistry.bin file you mention. This won't directly help you find a solution to your problem, but maybe will provide an extra clue for your search. These two links explain what that file is and how to open it: http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/07/15/about-the-new-privateregistry-bin-file-of-visual-studio-2017/ https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/examine_registry.md

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a possible workaround: try running devenv.exe with a /nosplash option. Taken from here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97594/visual-studio-2017-ide-fails-to-start-after-instal.html

Also, this appears to be fixed in Visual Studio v15.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can set devenv.exe like this. It works for me.

[image: Only Set Privilege Level]

Answer (score 0):

Running compatibility settings on and troubleshoot fixed this for me. And it set it to work with Windows 8 compatibility mode... and click next to save... after numerous uninstalling and reinstalling... that simple step fixed it.